# Google maps not displaying marker from a array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, maps

I am in need of some help. I have a google maps where I used a ajax call to return lat long - In the success I made a array and passed the php result in to that array. I then instanced a google map and tired to display the marker on the map. I got no error and I can see my ajax sent though. Some help would be greatly appreciated on why my markers or not showing up.

```
success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(result);
        var test1 = map_data.map; //This creates a instanc of google maps
        var location_array = [];
        var tech_loc = result['Success'][0].length;
        for(var i=0; i < tech_loc; i++){
            location_array.push(
                {
                    "lat": result['Success'][0][i][0],
                    "lng": result['Success'][0][i][1]
                });
        } console.log(JSON.stringify(location_array));

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //This places a marker on the map
            position: location_array,
            map: test1
        });
```

[image]

Comment: you're adding locations to an array (so multiple locations) and expect google to create a marker for each location in the array? A marker is a marker, not a bunch of markers, so, add each marker in the loop

Comment: Yes I am passing the location_array a list of lat and long. So yes there will be about 32 items in that array daily. And yes I need google to create the marker for each item in the array. Could you post a ex of what you mean by so, add each marker in the loop

Comment: then create a marker for each location (inside your loop) - `new google.maps.Marker` creates a *single* marker (otherwise it would be called `new google.maps.Markers` :p )

Comment: var test1 = map_data.map; //This creates a instance of google maps           var location_array = [];
var tech_loc = result['Success'][0].length;
           for(var i=0; i < tech_loc; i++){
                location_array.push(
                    {
                        "lat": result['Success'][0][i][0],
                        "lng": result['Success'][0][i][1]
                    });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //This places a marker on the map
                    position: location_array,
                    map: test1
                })
            }

Comment: `this is what my code looks like now` what is? you need to add each marker individually, unless google maps API has some method to use an array of locations to return an array of markers (easily written though) ... **please don't put long code in comments, it is unreadable**

Comment: you're still passing `position: location_array` ... rather than a **single location** ... see https://jsfiddle.net/xmmmd4hf/ for the correct way to do it (note, absolutely no need for location_array or var marker for that matter, but I kept that in there) - I'd do it like https://jsfiddle.net/xmmmd4hf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add individual markers.
Please refer to this link.
[Multiple Markers](https://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/)

```
// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```